# count rows that fulfill a condition

Tags: mysql, view

I really think the question I have is not too specific, I just don't know how to explain it.

Say I have a table with following Collumns

`team | gameType | date | outcome`

I would like to create a view that lists some statistics about the teams

`SELECT team, count(*) as FROM matches GROUP BY team ORDER BY total DESC`

Now I want to add columns counting the total

- which were league games
- which have been in the past month
- wins
- losses
- ties

The purpose is to create a view in the database, not any new tables or columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use case statements in your aggregation functions to aggregate only for specific events.

```
SELECT 
    team, 
    count(*) total_matches,
    count(case when gameType = 'league' then 1 end) league_matches,
    count(case then date > now() - INTERVAL 30 DAY then 1 end) recent_matches,
    ...
FROM matches 
GROUP BY team
```

Answer (score 3):

The general idea is to use CASE expression inside the aggregate

```
SELECT
    team,
    count(*) as total,
    count(CASE WHEN outcome = 'WIN' THEN 1 END) as wins,
    count(CASE WHEN outcome = 'DRAW' THEN 1 END) as draw,
    count(CASE WHEN outcome = 'LOSE' THEN 1 END) as losses,
    count(CASE WHEN gametype = 'League' THEN 1 END) as leaguegames,
    count(CASE WHEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) < dateTHEN 1 END) as lastmonth
FROM matches
GROUP BY team 
ORDER BY total DESC
```

Comment: @Konerak: no. COUNT(NULL) is ignored for the missing "ELSE" condition

Answer (score 3):

Somewhat simpler and more readable (to me at least) than using CASE is using OR:

```
SELECT
   team,
   count(*) as total,
   count(outcome = 'WIN'  OR NULL) as wins,
   count(outcome = 'DRAW' OR NULL) as draw,
   ...
FROM matches
GROUP BY team
```